# Vaadin: IllegalStateException "UI id has already been defined' after session timeout"

Tags: java, vaadin

My Vaadin application throws following exception after session timeout and page refresh attempt.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: UI id has already been defined
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:519)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.getBrowserDetailsUI(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:2468)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleBrowserDetailsRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:2362)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:325)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:201)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)...
```

I would appreciate any thoughts on what this means and why happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the reason of that exception was [this](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/springvaadinintegration) Spring integration plugin. I guess it was managing UI instances as singletones. We decided to use manual Spring context creation. That solved the problem.

Comment: By default spring components are singletons, unless you specify a different scope, such as prototype.

Comment: @Morfic That's true, but I didn't specify scope, integration plugin did. I couldn't change it.

Comment: You should be able to use `@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` or `@Scope("prototype")` to get a new bean instance every time. And probably you'd want `@PreserveOnRefresh` as well :)

Comment: It was a long ago, but I clearly remember using @Scope("prototype") and @PreserveOnRefresh in various combinations. Didn't work. Maybe that wasn't the case. I blame plugin :)

Answer (score 0):

This code removes problem for me

```
@PreserveOnRefresh
public class MyVaadinUI extends UI {
...
```

Comment: We had different problems.